# Error using `random.randint` "too many positional arguments"

Tags: python, random, dice

I had problems when making a call to random.randint(). I got the following error message in my program. I am using python 3.8, and I am not sure why this is happening. Below is the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\W\Desktop\All.py files\droll.py", line 13, in <module>
    roll=random.randint(1,
TypeError: randint() takes 3 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

## Here is my code

```
import random
def rule():
    print ("Roll the die!")
    print ("If you get a 1, you lose,")
    print ("And if you get a 6, you win.")
    print ("Anything inbetween does not count.")

rule()
#Main game loop
while True:
    q = input ("Are you ready to roll? (Y/N)").lower().strip()
    if q == "y":
        roll=random.randint(1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4,
                            5,
                            6)
        if (roll == 1):
            print ("You got a 1! You lost!")
        if (roll == 6):
            print ("You got a 6! You won!")
        else:
            print ("You got a middle roll!")
    if q == "n":
        print ("That's unfortunate.")
```

if anyone could help fix this problem, it would be much appreciated. I'm not sure if there is a new way to write random codes, and this has been bugging me for a while, as even the most simple code would not work. I've tried to fix this problem by adding a few more random.randints, and using if and statements, however that would sometimes result in 2 answers, or a blank space. If anyone has an answer, once again, I would much appreciate the help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple ways to generate random (and pseudorandom) numbers, commonly used functions include:

1. choice() :- used to generate a random number from a container.

   `roll = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`
2. randrange(beg, end, step) :- used to generate random number within a range specified (excluding end)

   `roll = random.randrange(1, 7, 1)`
3. randint() :- Yet another way...

   `roll = random.randint(1,6)`

Answer (score 1):

`random.randint` accepts two arguments – the lower bound and the upper bound.

Try

```
roll = random.randint(1,6)
```

instead of

```
roll = random.randint(1,
                      2,
                      3,
                      4,
                      5,
                      6)
```

[A description of `random.randint` in the Python documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.randint)

Comment: Unfortunately, this would not work, I need to have the middle numbers for the full dice roll. Thank you for taking the time to answer though!

Comment: This should work, as randint takes two parameters – the first is the lower value of the range and the second is the upper value of the range.

Comment: I was looking for a way to get a random chance for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Still, your answer explained something that I was confused about.